# Mongodb limit, offset and sort for lookup data

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, limit, lookup, offset

I need to run the lookup query on feeds via userrelavance collection

What I'm trying to achieve is :

1. I need relevant feeds of a user to be shown in the feeds list
2. Relevant feeds should be sorted by created_at considering all the userids in userreleavance collection
3. I need to keep a limit and offset values so that my relevant feeds can be paginated
4. Feeds in the lookup should fetch on sort by created_at (timestamp)

Below are my Mongo collections and schema

Feeds data:

```
    [
        {
            created_by:12,
            company_id:1,
            message:"Hi there"
            created_at:timestamp
        },
        {
            created_by:12,
            company_id:1,
            message:"how are you"
            created_at:timestamp
        }
        {
            created_by:13,
            company_id:1,
            message:"Hi",
            created_at:timestamp,
        },
        {
            created_by:13,
            company_id:1,
            message:"test",
            created_at:timestamp,
        },
        {
            created_by:14,
            company_id:1,
            message:"Hi",
            created_at:timestamp
        }
    ]

    userrelavance :

    {
     forUser:"10",
     userids:[12,13]
    }
```

I'm executing the query below:

```
    db.getCollection('userrelavance').aggregate(
    [
        {"$unwind":"$userids"},
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:'feeds',as:'feedObjects',let:{indicator_id:'$userids'},
                pipeline:[
                    {$match:{$expr:{$eq:['$created_by','$$indicator_id']}}},
                    {$limit:2}
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
```

Which is fetching the results, but giving 2 feed objects for every user in the userids (stored in relavance collection) array, but I need 2 feed objects sorted by created_at considering all the records of userids

Expected : get only 2 feed objects considering all the userids, and sort on created_at

Fetched :

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ddfc086782e53f39346b439"),
        "userids" : 12,
        "feedObjects" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d285ae2f44e3b584bf9205c"),
                "tags" : [ 
                    1400
                ],
                "message": "Hi there",
                "company_id" : 1,
                "feed_type" : "post",
                "status" : 1,
                "last_activity_date" : "1550839447440"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d285ae2f44e3b584bf9205d"),
                "tags" : [ 
                    1400
                ],
                "message":"How are you?"
                "company_id" : 1,
                "feed_type" : "greeting",
                "status" : 1,
                "last_activity_date" : "34534534534534534534534"
            }, 
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ddfc086782e53f39346b439"),
        "userids" : 13,
        "feedObjects" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d285ae2f44e3b584bf9205e"),
                "tags" : [ 
                    1400
                ],
                "company_id" : 1,
                "feed_type" : "post",
                "status" : 1,
                "last_activity_date" : "34345345345345"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d285ae2f44e3b584bf9205f"),
                "tags" : [ 
                    1400
                ],
                "company_id" : 1,
                "feed_type" : "post",
                "status" : 1,
                "last_activity_date" : "345435345345345"
            }, 
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried with limit on lookup , which is giving the results based on limit for every userid in the array, which should not be the case in my requirment, i need lookup results overall limit conidering all the userids